# Does Moonlight work on linux in Google Chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu-10.04, silverlight, moonlight

I'm trying to install [Moonlight](http://go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx), but I can only find instructions for setting it up in Firefox. And in the Ubuntu 10.04 repositories, I found a "moonlight-plugin-mozilla" package, but not "moonlight-plugin-chrome" (or similar). Is there any way to do this, or does Moonlight not yet run in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

"New Silverlight for Linux Release (Moonlight 3 Preview 6)
With Chrome support"

http://go-mono.com/moonlight/prerelease.aspx

It *should* support it, but I haven't got a Linux system nearby at the moment. Sorry if this doesnt help.

Comment: I tried it now, and it did not work on my computer. Ubuntu 9.10, updated. Chrome 5.0.375.70 beta.

Comment: Check this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1287825 | You may have to install the nonfree codecs (chromium-nonfree or what.. just search for chromium in your package manager and you'll find it.)